# Bind ItemsControl to two lists within nested itemscontrol

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to stick to MVVM patterns with my application, and am struggling with one aspect.

In "MainVM" I have an observable collection:

```
public ObservableCollection<Track> TrackList = new ObservableCollection<Track>();
```

Then in a user control I have an `ItemsControl` that is bound to a collection of "Blocks". The user can add or remove these blocks. Within a given block, I have another `ItemsControl` which is bound to that first `TrackList` like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MainWindow}, Path=DataContext.TrackList}"  ..../>
```

This works well, but I would like to add a checkbox to this nested ItemsControl and have it bound to a list within the `Block`, not the `Track`.

Something like this:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding  BlockCheckList[CurrentIndex]}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

The idea is to have each Block have a list of `bool` values that correspond to the initial `TrackList`.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: What is the `Track`, `Block` and `BlockCheckList`?

Comment: `Track` and `Block` are just simple classes. I tried to remove unnecessary information but maybe I could have used generic names. `BlockCheckList` would be a list of `bool` that is the same length as `TrackList`.